# Sympy check if a number is natural

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, sympy

If I some random number, how do I check if it's an integer (∈ ℕ)?

```
>>> from sympy.core.numbers import Float
>>> Float(2)
2.00000000000000
>>> Float(2).is_integer
False # what ??
```

I've found a simple workaround but I feel It's some kind of a hack:

```
>>> Float(2) % 1 == 0
True
>>> Float(2.5) % 1 == 0
False
```

So is there a more proper way of finding if a number is natural ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of query arises throughout the SymPy codebase and the solution that we have for this is to use `as_int` on the expression in question. When the `strict` flag is off, a float that is equivalent to the int will be returned as an int. Otherwise (or if the expression is not an integer) a ValueError will be raised:

```
>>> from sympy import Float
>>> from sympy.core.compatibility import as_int
>>> as_int(2.0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
... 
ValueError: 2.0 is not an integer

>>> as_int(2.0, strict=False)
2
```

Using this in a test function gives:

```
>>> def isint(i):
...     try: as_int(i, strict=False)
...     except: return False
...     return True
>>> isint(Float(2))
True
```

Another way to approach this is to check whether the decimal portion of a number is 0:

```py
>>> (Float(2)%1).is_zero
True
```

UPDATE:
In version 1.12 `as_int` can be imported from sympy.utilities.misc. And in 1.13 the `int_valued` can be imported from sympy.core.numbers:

```py
>>> from sympy.core.number import int_valued
>>> int_valued(0.5)
False
>>> int_valued(1.0)
True
```

Comment: If you are working with SymPy numbers, it is the best we have come up with. It is basically testing whether `n == int(n)` and watching out for cases that might raise an error. But if you are only passing numbers then `isint = lambda x: x == int(x)`.

Comment: Not bad as an idea. My hack is 4 times faster (tested it with `timeit`) but it's not a big deal

Comment: I'll except the answer congrats and thank you

Comment: OP - generally `performance` and `sympy` don't go together.  We use `sympy` because we want the generality of symbolic calculations.  For pure number work, stick with plain Python, or `numpy` for arrays.

Comment: I use it because it can simplify square roots and long complicated expressions

Comment: Nowadays (Sympy 1.12 - but may be also with some previous versions) the correct import is:

    `from sympy.utilities.misc import as_int`